# Apply CSS to first type and other conditions together

Tags: css

I got a few divs with class A, then I want to check that whether the first A has class B or not, if yes then apply some styles. Would like to use CSS only.

Update: the first div should be something else.
For example,

Condition 1:

```
<div class="container">    
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="A"></div> <!-- don't apply style -->
  <div class="A B"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A B"></div>
</div>
```

Condition 2:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="C"></div>    
  <div class="A B"></div> <!--apply style -->
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CBroe it's pretty hard to go from the answers there to what OP asked. Tbh I think that what OP wants is not possible with CSS only

Comment: Edit: Cédric answer is actually valid

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Hi thanks for checking, please allow me update the condition and that is not working for new condition. I did try it before raising this~

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina _"Tbh I think that what OP wants is not possible with CSS only"_ - yes, same, and the explanation for that can be found in the duplicate, IMHO. Sometimes "not possible" _is_ the valid answer.

Comment: @MingzeLi just replace `:first-of-type` with `:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Hi thanks the code is working, this correct my understand ing of nth-of-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

As [Christian Vincenzo Traina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850851/christian-vincenzo-traina) suggested in comment, select the second nth-of-type A that has the class B with `.A:nth-of-type(2).B`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.A,
.C {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.A:nth-of-type(2).B {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <!-- don't apply style -->
  <div class="A B"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A B"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="A B"></div>
  <!--apply style -->
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```

**OLDER ANSWER**

*note : the older question asked without the div.C class*

Select the first-of-type A that has the class B with `.A:first-of-type.B`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.A {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.A:first-of-type.B {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <!-- don't apply style -->
  <div class="A B"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A B"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="A B"></div>
  <!--apply style -->
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , could you help to check the new condition? Given answer will not apply for new condtions~ Thanks